# USB receptables for power delivery?

Tags: power-supply, usb, usb-c, usb-pd, power-delivery

I'm not totally sure this is the right place to ask, but does anyone know of any USB C receptacles for low voltage and current power delivery? I can't find a good option with a good schematic.

Comment: Note that in the context of USB, "Power Delivery" is a very specific function supported by negotiation data to achieve relatively high current.  Are you talking about support for the USB-PD protocol, or merely bus-powered devices.

Comment: And are you wanting to _supply_ the power or _consume_ it? The question is very unclear.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh. By this I just meant delivering power.

Comment: @TypeIA Consume it from USB C and then supply it to my internal circuitry

Comment: How much power, how much voltage, how much current? USB connectors of various types definitely used for low voltage and low amperage power delivery.

Comment: @Justme Well, I'm using a voltage regulator to make sure it's exactly 5V, and at most 1A.

Comment: No, this is not the right place to ask. "Shopping" is off-topic.

Comment: @brhans Where should I ask then?

Comment: I don't know. Not every question has a home at Stack Exchange, where shopping is off-topic on almost every stack.

Comment: I am aware, what site would be ideal? Reddit?

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious here, but aren't all USB-C connectors rated for at least 5V and at least 1A, or have you not found any?

Comment: @Justme Yes, but I can't find a good choice on Mouser or Digikey? What would you usually use?

Comment: *"I can't find a good choice at Mouser ..."* – What exactly are you missing in this [choice](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/USB-Connectors/_/N-88hmf?P=1ysnwh3)?

Comment: @CATboardBETA Asking for products what to buy and places where to buy them are off topic. You won't get an answer to that question. I thought you in general asked if USB receptacles can be used for power delivery. Besides I would not know what kind of connector you would find suitable, there are so many different kind. If I suggested something, you would say you can't use that because some thing X which you did not mention.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but let me try to disentangle it a bit.

If you are *consuming* power, the nomenclature for that in USB-C is called an "Upstream Facing Port" (UFP).  Doing that only requires two resistors on the CC lines and you can consume up to 900mA at 5V.  If you put something like the TUSB320 series from TI (other manufacturers have similar chips), they will negotiate on the CC lines and you can pull up to 5V at up to 3A.

Unfortunately, it sounds like you are *supplying* power and that's a *lot* more complicated.  The nomenclature for that in USB-C is called a "Downstream Facing Port" (DFP).  Your solution has to do things like monitor for shorts, disconnects, renegotiation, etc. so you would need to have a significantly more complicated solution that is capable of monitoring and disconnecting power under failure conditions.  A lot of USB-C cables have active circuitry, so don't think that you can just jam power through them and ignore the CC negotiation--it might work, but it also won't work a lot of the time, too.

As for specifications, I don't think I've ever seen a USB-C receptacle that wasn't rated to full USB-C PD (Power Delivery) specifications (20V at 5A aka 100W).  However, they should almost certainly all be capable of 5V at 3A.

Good luck.